# What are the duration values of Bootstrap 4 transitions?

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-transitions, duration

The transitional changing of a button's colour on mouseover or the toggling movement of a [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/) are defined as CSS transitions. My question is, in which file(s) of Bootstrap can I look up the duration values of these?

(For buttons it feels like ~0.2s, Collapses are animated a little longer, I would say around .4) But I would need the exact values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the devtools and inspect the element during its expansion, you can see the transition duration:

[image: GIF demonstration]

It's 0.35s.

If you inspect the button, its transition durations are 0.15s.